# Enable alpha layer with OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I use OpenGL with Lwjgl in Java.

I just want to render my texture with alpha layer, but actually, it looks like this :
http://puu.sh/8FRzn.png

My configuration of OpenGL :

```
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);   

    glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  


    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Et how I load my sprite sheet :

```
BLA BLA BLA ..
public static HashMap<String, Integer> loadTexture(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(w * h *4);

    for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            Color color = new Color(pixels[x + y * w]);

            buffer.put((byte)color.getRed());
            buffer.put((byte)color.getGreen());
            buffer.put((byte)color.getBlue());
            buffer.put((byte)color.getAlpha());
        }
    }
    buffer.flip();

    int id = glGenTextures();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    hashMap.put("width", w);
    hashMap.put("height", h);
    hashMap.put("id", id);

    return hashMap;
}
```

And I render it with common method : GL_QUADS

Yes, my texture have a Alpha Layer : http://puu.sh/8FS15.png

I already searched across the web to find answer but my OpenGL "Configuration" is the same as the solutions given each time ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an issue with BufferedImage not having the alpha channel enabled. Try creating you Buffered Image first like this.

By default when you load an image as a BufferedImage, it does not load the alpha layers of said image. You must define this parameter in the BufferedImage constructor. However the problem is, that when loading an image through ImageIO, the BufferedImage is created for you and you are not able to set this option. By creating an empty image with the width and height of the first image, you are able to set this parameter in the new image. You can then modify the pixels of that image through use of the Graphics2D class, which will allow you to draw the original image(the one loaded through ImageIO onto the new one that has alpha support). It may seem a bit jumbled, but the code example below should be able to refine this explanation a bit.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(int width, int height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

This will tell it to load the alpha channel with the BufferedImage.

You will need to load the image in a separate BufferedImage first to get the width and height, then redraw it with a graphics class.

Here is a full example:

```
    try {
        BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        this.image = image;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The final this.image refers to your main image in the start of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You solved my problem :D !

But .. I dont understand why doing this way works ? It will be very nice if you could explain :) !

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've edited my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hmmm actually is doesn't work, It just set the alpha layer black but not transparent : 

http://puu.sh/8GgaD.png

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Are you exporting your images with actual transparency, I'm not sure what editor you're using, but for example when you use GIMP, when you export a PNG you have the option to "Save background color of transparent pixels", if this is chosen, it will save a color to these transparent pixels rather than actual transparency. I would check that real quick.

Comment: I think I've found the issue, wherever you actually draw this to the screen, you should call glDepthMask(false); before, and glDepthMask(true); afterwards. Try that and let me know.

Comment: It change nothing ..  
The result is the same, I really don't understand :/

Comment: So, I tried to import my texture via Slick Utils and It works, I will search for the sources and find what's different. I'll let you know.